# WSO2 App Manager single sign-on across mobile applications

Tags: wso2

I would like to ask is there any method or documentation for this newly released WSO2 App Manager to configure for single sign-on across mobile application as promoted ? (e.g. http://www.openhealthnews.com/content/wso2-founder-and-ceo-unveil-latest-product-developments-harnessing-today%E2%80%99s-connected-world-w)

I have tried search every where but found nothing as yet when it comes to SSO acorss application for mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 App Manager 1.0.0 does not support in-app management features such as SSO for mobile apps. Current version of App Manager only support single sign-on (SSO) across web applications.